# Reactjs application can not reach my Spring Boot backend using https requests

Tags: reactjs, rest, spring-boot, post, https

I have a ReactJS application running on https://localhost:8080 and i would like to POST data to my Spring Boot backend app running on https://localhost:8443, but when i try to POST data..i get this error in my browser console:

TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8443/api/... (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

My Spring Boot application not using Spring Security. I enabled HTTPS by [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_enabling_https.htm) tutorial. I running my ReactJS application with `HTTPS=true npm start` and i changed the react application port like `"start": "PORT=8080 react-scripts start"` inpackage.json

This is my application.properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store-password = password
server.ssl.key-store-type = PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias = tomcat
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

and here is how t tried to call the REST API from React:

```
fetch('https://localhost:8443/api/..., {
            method: 'POST'
        }).then((data) => {
            if (data.ok) {
                this.setState({ 
                response: data })
            }
        })
        .catch(console.log);
```

Here is my @RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MessageReceiverResource {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "https://localhost:8080")
    @PostMapping
    public Response receiveMessages(@RequestBody Request request){
           ...
        return response;
    }
}
```

This solution just worked fine until I enabled HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding this line to package.json: `"proxy": "https://localhost:8443",`